# How to design a distributed system for "finding something within X miles"?

Tags: distributed-computing

Question:

> Design a distributed system to response the clients' query about "finding something within X miles".

If X is infinite, get all the "something" in the world (if they are all stored in your database)

Answer (score 0):

You can think about two approaches:

- *when the number of potential results is small and number of queries big* divide the space of coordinates between available machines and send queries only to machines which are responsible for areas which intersect with X-mile circle
- *when the number of potential results is big* store objects dispersed, so that they are uniformly distributed on all machines (you can choose the machine by randomization or by objects' origin - it depends) and post every query to all machines and merge received results.

Further changes depend on getting more information about the problem nature.

Comment: According to the division of space into parts see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

Comment: Is there a good strategy for partition the whole data set? for example, we can store adjancent things into one table, but how to handle the query in the border of the partition?

Comment: as long, as the addressing is consistent through the application, your border handling is good